# Spring Injection with Servlets: NoSuchBean

Tags: spring, servlets, dependency-injection

New to Spring, and working with Spring 3.2.5 trying to get injection to work with a servlet in a vanilla web app (i.e., it's not a Spring MVC web app - it's a pre-existing app I'm extending using the Spring framework).  The container is Tomcat 7.0.47.

My problem is that I'm getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException errors (No bean named 'MyServlet' is defined) when I hit the servlet.  There are no errors at startup, so at least one of my beans (the ServiceImplementation bean) is getting successfully instantiated.  The problem appears to be with finding the HttpRequestHandler-derived bean (MyServlet) when a new HTTP request comes in.

The full stack trace for the exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'MyServlet' is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.init(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:58)
    com.random.webapp.MySpringServlet.init(Unknown Source)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I followed this pattern for my setup:
http://andykayley.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-inject-spring-beans-into.html

...with one minor (I think) twist.  I have a class derived from HttpRequestHandlerServlet so that I can override the init method with some application-specific stuff.  The extension class looks like this:

```
public class MySpringServlet extends HttpRequestHandlerServlet
{
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        super.init();
        appSpecificInit();
    }
}
```

The servlet I want injected looks like this:

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpRequestHandler
{
    private IService _service = null;

    public void setService( IService theService ) {
        _service = theService;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response)
                              throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        _service.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The implementation I want it injected with looks like this:

```
public class ServiceImplementation implements IService
{
    @Override
    public void DoSomething()
    {
                // some code goes here
    }
}
```

These are the relevant entries in web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-INF/implementation.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.random.webapp.MySpringServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myservlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is the applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="MyServlet" class="com.random.webapp.MyServlet">
    <property name="Service" ref="ServiceImplementation" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

...and this is what implementation.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

 <bean id="ServiceImplementation" class="com.random.webapp.ServiceImplementation">
 </bean>

</beans>
```

I've been back and forth between the web.xml, applicationContext.xml, and implementation.xml files to double and triple check my configuration, and I don't see anything wrong with any of them, but I'm obviously missing something.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Added the full exception stack trace - I'm trying to get ServiceImplementation setter-injected into MyServlet's service property.

Comment: I just copy pasted your whole code and it works fine for me. Are you sure you are showing us your true configuration?

Comment: Make sure you clean and re-compile your project.

Comment: Hmm - perhaps there is a problem with the way I have deployed the app to Tomcat.  I'm not running it in place from where it was built - I'm generating a WAR folder and copying its contents into Tomcat's webapp folders.  I will double-check this deployment configuration to see if I've gummed something up there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you are getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'MyServlet' is defined
```

occurs in the `init()` method of the `HttpRequestHandlerServlet` which tries to load a delegate `HttpRequestHandler` object from your context based on the name you give the `HttpRequestHandlerServlet` in your `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.random.webapp.MySpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

In the configuration above, that would be `MyServlet`. Although it appears you have it correct in

```
<bean id="MyServlet" class="com.random.webapp.MyServlet">
    <property name="Service" ref="ServiceImplementation" />
</bean>
```

make sure you are loading the correct context file as declared here

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-INF/implementation.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: How can I verify that the correct context file is being loaded?  There are only 3 xml files in WEB-INF: web.xml, applicationContext.xml, and implementation.xml

Comment: I have heard that there can be a hierarchy of Spring application contexts, like a ROOT context, and some others in a web app.  Is that concept relevant here?

Comment: @Hoobajoob If they are there, you should be fine. Double check that the contents are what you say they are. As for the hierarchy, no. You load one single context, the root context, when you declare your `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: Ah crap - it was a simple case error: myServlet instead of MyServlet - I had updated the config in my workspace but not copied the update to the deployed web app.  Thanks!

Comment: Technically, I guess the correct answer came from your comments suggesting to verify the config contents, but I marked yours as the answer anyway.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Hoobajoob You're welcome. My advice when you get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is check your context for a bean definition, then check where you try to load the bean definition. One step will lead to the other.